# Convolve integer tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I'm trying to run a convolution (standard `depthwise_conv2d`) on a `tf.int32` batch with a `tf.int32` filter. I get the error: `TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType int32 not in list of allowed values: float32, float64`. Given that I don't need gradients, I'm wondering if anybody knows an op that can express a convolution, and that accepts ints? Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to type cast it to float?. Convolution involves normalisation which will anyway make the output float.

Comment: hey -- thanks for the comment. was unaware that convolution involved any normalization, and looking [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc), which seems to eventually call out to [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/9b065de03d016d802a25366ff5f0055df6318121/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-wzxhzdk178operationwzxhzdk179-convolveconst-kernel-kernel-const-dimensions-dims), I don't see where the normalization is happening. Ended up using NumPy which is fine for now

Comment: In normal convolution,  the normalization is absorbed in the kernel weights. But your question was on  integer convolution (which i thought u want to do for some reason),  then there will be normalization involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this because [conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) does not accept int types:

> input: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: half, float32. A
>   4-D tensor. The dimension order is interpreted according to the value
>   of data_format, see below for details.

So your solutions are either write your own conv2dint (which will be just a copy of their conv2d with different types) or use their conv2d and apply `tf.cast(res_from_conv, tf.int32)`.